# How to use multiple UIAlertView inside one IBAction with different button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, ibaction

Is it possible to show different alerts with different buttons in the same IBAction based on different conditions?? I have some code in IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)btnRecommendationTapped:(id)sender {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Recommendation"
                                                      message: @"It seems that you are interested in the %d of this collection."
                                                     delegate: nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                            otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", @"No", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

I would like to have another alert shows "Sorry! we are unable to provide any recommendation" with a ok button. when the condition has fulfilled shows the one in IBAction otherwise shows this one.

Comment: `if (condition) { create alertView } else { create other alertView }`?!

Comment: What's the condition? Have you heard of an `if statement`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
   {
          if([sender tag]==0)
         {
           UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"button 1 clicked" delegate:self 
            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
         }
         else if ([sender tag]==1)
         {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"button 2 clicked" delegate:self
           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
         }
         else if ([sender tag]==2)
         {
          UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"button 3 clicked" delegate:self
           cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
                [alert show];
         }
}
```

Comment: Convention says that `ButtonClicked:` should be `buttonClicked:`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different ways you could do this. You could use an `if statement` which creates different `UIAlertView`s based on the condition.

**Option 1:**

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *ourAlertView; // Create the local variable, we don't need to create multiple ones we can just set to the one.
    // This is your if statement to determine if your condition has been met
    // Whatever that condition is here we're going to assume you have set a BOOL
    // flag before hand called failed.
    if(!failed) {
        ourAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Recommendations"
                                                  message:@"We recommend..."
                                                 delegate:self // Very important
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [ourAlertView setTag:0]; // Would recommend setting a tag to determine which one has been used in the delegate methods.
    } else { // else if() if you want more then 2
        ourAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry"
                                                  message:@"We're sorry..."
                                                 delegate:self // Very important
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [ourAlertView setTag:1];
    }

    [ourAlertView show];
}
```

The second option would very simpler but we would do the following, still using an `if statement` but we only create one `UIAlertView`

**Option 2:**

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
     // We create an empty `UIAlertView` only setting the delegate to self.
     UIAlertView *ourAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                               message:nil
                                              delegate:self // Very important
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];

     if(!failed) {
        [ourAlertView setTitle:@"Recommendations"];
        [ourAlertView setMessage:@"We recommend..."];
        [ourAlertView addButtonWithTitle:@"No"];
        [ourAlertView addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
        [ourAlertView setCancelButtonIndex:0];
        [ourAlertView setTag:0];
     } else {
        [ourAlertView setTitle:@"Sorry"];
        [ourAlertView setMessage:@"We're sorry..."];
        [ourAlertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
        [ourAlertView setCancelButtonIndex:0];
        [ourAlertView setTag:1];
     }

     [ourAlertView show];
}
```

But the most important thing that is required (That is if you want it to work properly) that a lot of people forget about is the `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

So in your `.h` file where you have the `@interface` set you need to do

```
@interface MySubClass : MySuperClass <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

this will allow you to use the following methods from the `UIAlertViewDelegate`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
- (void)alertViewCancel:(UIAlertView *)alertView
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
```

Checkout both the [`UIAlertView` Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertView/firstOtherButtonIndex) and the [`UIAlertViewDelegate` Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html)

**Very Important Note about subclassing** from Apple documentation on `UIAlertView` you most comply too.

> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified

Answer (score 0):

try as follow:

```
- (IBAction)btnRecommendationTapped:(id)sender {
if(condition has fulfilled){
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Recommendation"
                                                      message: @"It seems that you are interested in the %d of this collection."
                                                     delegate: nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                            otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", @"No", nil];
[alert show];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Sorry! we are unable to provide any recommendation"
                                                      message: nil"
                                                     delegate: nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle: nil
                                            otherButtonTitles: @"Ok", nil];
[alert show];

}
}
```

Comment: Is the additional `"` a typo if it's not your answer is wrong.